# Why is my x86 assembly program only giving the correct result for subtraction and not for other operators?

Tags: assembly, x86

The Code:

```
`IDEAL
MODEL small
STACK 100h

DATASEG
    num1 dw ?
    num2 dw ?
    operator db ?
    result dw ?
    prompt1 db "Enter first number: $"
    prompt2 db "Enter operator (+, -, *, /): $"
    prompt3 db "Enter second number (second number should be smaller than first): $"
    outputMsg db "Result: $"
    string db 10 dup('$')
    debugMsg db "Operator value: $" 

CODESEG
start:
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax


    mov dl, 0ah
    mov ah, 2h
    int 21h
    
    
    ; ask for first number
    mov ah, 09h
    mov dx, offset prompt1
    int 21h
    
    ; read first number
    mov ah, 1h
    int 21h
    sub al, '0'
    mov [num1], ax
    
    mov dl, 0ah
    mov ah, 2h
    int 21h


    ; ask for operator
    mov ah, 09h
    mov dx, offset prompt2
    int 21h

    ; read operator
    mov ah, 1h
    int 21h
    mov [operator], al
    
    
    mov dl, 0ah
    mov ah, 2h
    int 21h
    
    
    ;print operator value for debugging
    mov ah, 09h
    mov dx, offset debugMsg
    int 21h
    mov dl, [operator]
    mov ah, 2h
    int 21h
    
    
    mov dl, 0ah
    mov ah, 2h
    int 21h
    

    ; ask for second number
    mov ah, 09h
    mov dx, offset prompt3
    int 21h

    ;read second number
    mov ah, 1h
    int 21h
    sub al, '0'
    mov [num2], ax

    mov dl, 0ah
    mov ah, 2h
    int 21h

    ; do calculation
    cmp [operator], '+'
    je ADDITION
    cmp [operator], '-'
    je SUBTRACTION
    cmp [operator], '*'
    je MULTIPLICATION
    cmp [operator], '/'
    je DIVISION
    jmp EXIT
        
ADDITION:
    mov ax, [num1]
    add ax, [num2]
    mov [result], ax
    jmp OUTPUT

SUBTRACTION:
    mov ax, [num1]
    sub ax, [num2]
    mov [result], ax
    jmp OUTPUT

MULTIPLICATION:
    mov ax, [num1]
    mul [num2]
    mov [result], ax
    jmp OUTPUT

DIVISION:
    mov ax, [num1]
    mov dx, 0
    div [num2]
    mov [result], ax
    jmp OUTPUT
    
OUTPUT: ;show result
    mov ah, 09h
    mov dx, offset outputMsg
    int 21h  

    mov bx, 10 
    mov cx, 0   
    mov ax, [result]    

l1:
    mov dx, 0     
    div bx        
    add dl, '0'     
    push dx         
    inc cx        
    cmp ax, 0     
    jne l1         
    mov bx, offset string  
l2:
    pop dx         
    mov [bx], dl   
    inc bx         
    loop l2       

    mov ah, 09h    
    mov dx, offset string
    int 21h
    
    
    mov dl, 0ah
    mov ah, 2h
    int 21h
    
    
exit:
    mov ax, 4c00h
    int 21h

END start
`
```

I am very new to assembly and programming in general and I'm trying to create a very simple calculator, the calculator should receive a single digit number, an operator and a second single digit number, calculate the answer and display. I've been having this problem for a long time now, for some reason I just can't get the output to work, the problem with the code above is that the calculation is incorrect for any operator except the minus.

To be honest I didn't try much because I don't know what as I am very new to assembly, The only thing I did try is to make ChatGBT fix my problems, but it keeps failing again and again):

Comment: Try debugging it using single step, compare the operation that works with the ones that don't

Comment: For assembly programming I find that drawing a flow-chart before actually writing any code usually helps formulating and writing the code. Have you tried to draw a flow-chart for your program? Start simple and high-level. Then go through a couple iterations adding more details, almost to the level of the actual assembly structures.

Comment: Or at least caveman-debug it; print out num1 and num2 prior to the dispatch below 'do calculation' and have each potential jump target — ADDITION, SUBTRACTION, etc — print their name.

Comment: All other things being correct, the most likely explanation from a very brief look at the code is that the subtraction removed the garbage in `ah`. You read a char in `al` and convert it to a number, still in `al`. But then you store `ax` and work with WORDs later. However `ah` is "undefined" after you just read a char. Store only `al` or set `ah` to zero before the store (or zero extend).

Comment: @Tommy: Debug-prints suck in asm because you can't do anything without modifying registers, and register state is where your program logic exists.  (Or where it *should* exist, not just memory.)  Also, unless you're linking some library, you have to write your own function for integer -> ASCII decimal string and writing it to stdout.  Writing a non-intrusive debug-print for asm is a lot of work and easy to get wrong.  That's one reason why using a debugger is more important and useful for asm than most other langs. Also asm allows bugs that are hard to spot without one, like incorrect jumps.

Comment: @MargaretBloom: I tried storing only al as you suggested, and the result was that now when I use the multiplication operator it works correctly, but now the results of the minus and plus operators are for some reason 512 larger than the correct result, and the division operator now just goes into an infinite loop or crashes. The problems might be that I just misunderstood or implemented your suggestion incorrectly but still.

Comment: @PeterCordes given that it’s a calculator that outputs a result, integer to ASCII is already present — see from after the first int 21h below OUTPUT.

Comment: @Tommy: True, but notice that as it exists now, it's not a function that returns (it ends with to an exit system call), and it's hard-coded to print a 2-byte integer from `result`, and to overwrite the `string db 10 dup('$')` buffer which will be a problem later if you print a longer result now and later you want to printing a shorter results that doesn't overwrite all those digits before getting to a `$`.  Also it trashes all the register values.  So yes, assuming it's non-buggy, you're close to having something you can turn into a function you can call, if you can do that without bugs...

Comment: @PeterCordes not disagreeing, just bouncing ideas: then perhaps he could try a series of successive one line modifications: (i) outputting num1 instead of really; (ii) num2; (iii) loading result with different hard-coded values based on the operation dispatched to.

Comment: @Tommy: Well sure.  I think for me the biggest argument is that using a debugger is such an essential skill for learning asm that it's more helpful to spend time learning to use a debugger than futzing with debug-prints.

Comment: Anyone please, I'm going crazy of over this